# How to send email message content as HTML rather than plain text?

Tags: email, html, gnu, mailutils

Currently I send an email from the Linux command like this:

```
echo "Here is the link: file:///S:/some_doc.html" | mail -s "Here is some_doc.html" fred@example.com
```

In some email clients the "file:///S:/some_doc.html" in the message body becomes a link that the user can click on but in other
clients it is presented as plain text requiring the user to copy and paste the string into a web browser.
How do I modify the command to make the message be HTML so that the email client will know how to handle the link?

This gets the link into the message but it is still treated like text not HTML:

```
echo "Here is the link to: <a href='file:///S:/some_doc.html'>some_doc.html</a>" | mail -s "Here is some_doc.html" fred@example.com
```

Comment: Why should a perfectly valid Super User question with an **accepted answer** be moved to another SE site?

Comment: It is a Linux specific question which now that there is a SE site for Linux it would be the natural place that someone asking this question would go. If the question was regarding the distinction between text and HTML in email rather than about a "Linux command" then it would be better located here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've seen it done:

```
mail -a "Content-type: text/html;" -s Test address@example.com < mail_html.html
```

I should have mentioned, I tested this on Ubuntu Server 10.04_x64 with [Gnu Mail Utils](https://mailutils.org/) -> [Postfix](http://www.postfix.org/)

Comment: My `mail` doesn't have -a, could you be thinking of `mutt`, which does support it?

Comment: A better way would be to create a MIME `multipart/alternative` message with `text/plain` and `text/html` parts containing identical text, instead of just sending HTML directly.

Comment: @Rich: It's there in `mail` of GNU _Mailutils_. You probably have the more traditional _BSD mailx_. (Beware: `mail` of _Heirloom mailx_ and `mutt` use `-a` for something entirely different – attaching a file.)

Comment: not working in centos 8

Answer (score 1):

Message:

- The best way is to create a MIME `Content-Type: multipart/alternative` message with `text/plain` and `text/html` parts.
- For the lazy, `Content-Type: text/html` (with HTML straight in message body) will do.

  ...but remember that there *are* mail clients that are unable to display HTML.
- Whichever you choose, **add a `charset=utf-8`** (as in `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`) to the type header. (Any non-Unicode charset (except perhaps `us-ascii` and `iso-8859-1`) is evil.)

Sending:

- Nathaniel suggested `mail -a "Content-Type: text/html"`, but this only works with GNU Mailutils.
- A more reliable way is to pipe the message `sendmail`, but you will have to construct all headers on your own.

  ```
  rcpt=joe@example.com
  echo -e "From: <$USER>\nTo: <$rcpt>\nDate: $(date "+%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z")\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n\n<!DOCTYPE html>\n<p>Here is the link to: <a href=\"file:///S:/some_doc.html\">some_doc.html</a>" | sendmail -i "$rcpt"
  ```